# Parameters (aesthetics) of geometric objects (geoms) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not understand when to place a parameter of a geom in the aes()-function an when not. Here a simple example:

The code

```
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total), color="red")

print(p)
```

works as fine as the variation

```
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total),color="red")

print(p)
```

Yet, whereas

```
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total), shape=2)

print(p)
```

is fine, the following does not work:

```
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total, shape=2))

print(p)
```

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Inside `aes()` you **map** aesthetics to columns of your data. Outside `aes()` you **set** it to a constant. In your last attempt `ggplot2` will map the size aesthetics to a variable called `"2"` which is constant for all observations. Hence all points have the same size.

Comment: See: https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-mapping-vs-setting/

Comment: One helpful link, indeed. Thx, markus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As markus explained, the general principle is that you use arguments inside `aes()` to map a variable in your data to an aesthetic. In contrast, arguments outside `aes()` are setting aesthetics manually (e.g. `color = "red"` rather than `color = region`).

Part of your confusion might be stemming from the fact that by coincidence the default color ggplot2 picks first is red. When you place `color = "red"` inside `aes()` you are getting red dots, but only because the color you picked happened to be the default color:

```
ggplot(data=murders) +
    geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total, color="red"))
```

[image]

You will see this more clearly if you try a different color:

```
ggplot(data=murders) +
    geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total, color="green"))
```

[image]

Why did the dots stay red, even after you changed the color to green? In this case you might think you are using a string to specify the name of a color ("red" or "green") but you are actually setting the color aesthetic to a constant variable (since the length of the character vector is one) and the default color just happens to be red.

If you want to specify a color manually place the color outside of `aes()`:

```
ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total), color="green")
```

[image]

And if you want to specify a color based on a column in your data place the color inside `aes()`:

```
ggplot(data=murders) +
  geom_point(aes(x=population, y=total), color=region)
```

[image]

The same principle will apply to shape, or any other aesthetic you will add to your plots. You can refer to the [Data Visualization](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) chapter from R for Data Science for additional explanation and examples of these principles.